# Can't figure out how to get rid of Snap.do

Tags: malware

Every time I start Chrome there is the Snap.do page that seems to be set as the homepage no matter how many times I've changed the homepage settings on Chrome and I've removed Snap.do from extensions and it doesn't show up there any longer. A lot of forums said that I needed to delete the file via Control Panel first but it doesn't even show up there.

Comment: This is not a constructive security question. In fact it is also too localised and off topic. As Xander says, if you have pernicious malware your best bet is to Google the specific removal process.

Answer (score 3):

There's a five step process documented [here](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/snap-do-toolbar-removal/).

The steps are:

1. Uninstall it via the control panel (or any program by Resoft Ltd)
2. Remove the extension from your browser, and change your search engine preferences and home page.
3. Remove its registry keys
4. Malware scan with MalwareBytes
5. Malware scan with Hitman Pro